# Google Compute Engine usually creates a disk from snapshot in 40 seconds, but I have had anomalies

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am having sporadic problems with europe-west1-b

From operations log:

> Create a disk      test   myemailwashere       Start: Aug 12, 2014 6:28:09 PM
>   End: Aug 12, 2014 6:59:52 PM   Done

This was operation-1407857288476-500705192f560-bd7b8adc-9e28b8d4

europe-west1-a worked as expected when I tested disk creation there

Comment: You may want to talk with Google Support.  You have not described the problem you faced sufficiently for us to help you here.

Comment: "Google engineers monitor and answer questions via Stack Overflow "
says Google's page at Google Compute

Comment: Yes ... for programming issues .. this is a performance issue and can/should be addressed via support.

Comment: seeing the same behaviour...